# Kivy Doesn't Download as a Package

Tags: python, download, kivy

I've been trying to download Kivy. In the instructions here, (http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) Kivy appears to be downloaded as a package, and then unzipped. When I tried to download Kivy, it appeared as a compressed folder, but didn't have the option to unzip it. If anyone has any idea what's going on, feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can a .zip not have an option to unzip? You just right-click and extract it like any other zip file on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regularly have trouble installing python modules. Normally I use easy_installer, but even that seems to choke occasionally. However, without fail this has always worked for me:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

It's an unofficial host for module binaries. Just download the relevant files, run them and you should be good to go. :)